# Get last modified and other file info from remote server with PHP

Tags: php, file, filesize, last-modified

1. A weekly mp3 is uploaded to an external server.
2. I manually copy this to my server and link it for podcasting and archive etc.
3. The external file is then replaced the following week.

I can copy the file directly to my server when available:

```
copy("http://source.com/file.mp3", "newfile.mp3");
```

I need to know when the file is available by getting other file info such as last modified so I can compare the files and copy the new file(s) only when they are updated. This works fine on my server, but not for an external source, is there an alternative?

```
echo filemtime($externalfile);
echo filectime($externalfile);
echo print_r(stat($externalfile));
```

Is it a security restriction to disallow access to this information?

I have access to the directory listing as a page, as a last resort I could access the last modified and sizes from that, but a direct solution would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you can try using [get_headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) and looking for the last-modified portion...

Or you could use the content-length header and compare it to the size of the current weeks mp3